# Accessing and changing structs as property vs as field

Tags: c#, struct

Ok, I'll start my question saying that I understand the evil behind mutable structs, but I'm working with SFML.net and using a lot of Vector2f and such structs.

What I don't get it is why I can have, and change the values of, a field in a class and can't do the same with a property, in the very same class.

Take a look at this code:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public struct TestStruct
    {
        public string Value;
    }

    class Program
    {
        TestStruct structA;
        TestStruct structB { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();

            // This Works
            program.structA.Value = "Test A";

            // This fails with the following error:
            // Cannot modify the return value of 'Test.Program.structB'
            // because it is not a variable
            //program.structB.Value = "Test B"; 

            TestStruct copy = program.structB;
            copy.Value = "Test B";

            Console.WriteLine(program.structA.Value); // "Test A"
            Console.WriteLine(program.structB.Value); // Empty, as expected
        }
    }
}
```

note: I'll build my own classes to cover the same functionality and keep with my mutability, but I can't see a technical reason why I can do one and can't do other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you access a field, you are accessing the actual struct. When you access it through property, you call a method that returns whatever is stored in the property. In the case of a struct, which is a value type, you will get back a copy of the struct. Apparently that copy is not a variable and cannot be changed.

Section "1.7 Structs" of the C# language specification 5.0 says:

> With classes, it is possible for two variables to reference the same
>   object and thus possible for operations on one variable to affect the
>   object referenced by the other variable. With structs, the variables
>   each have their own copy of the data, and it is not possible for
>   operations on one to affect the other.

That explains that you will receive a copy of the struct and not be able to modify the original struct. However, it doesn't describe why it isn't allowed.

Section "11.3.3" of the specifcation:

> When a property or indexer of a struct is the target of an assignment,
>   the instance expression associated with the property or indexer access
>   must be classified as a variable. If the instance expression is
>   classified as a value, a compile-time error occurs. This is described
>   in further detail in §7.17.1.

So the returned "thing" from the get accessor is a value and not a variable. That explains the wording in the error message.

The specification also contains an example in section 7.17.1 that is nearly identical to your code:

Given the declarations:

```
struct Point
{
    int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int X {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }
    public int Y {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }
}
struct Rectangle
{
    Point a, b;
    public Rectangle(Point a, Point b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public Point A {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; }
    }
    public Point B {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value; }
    }
}
```

in the example

```
Point p = new Point();
p.X = 100;
p.Y = 100;
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.A = new Point(10, 10);
r.B = p;
```

the assignments to p.X, p.Y, r.A, and r.B are permitted because p and r are variables. However, in the example

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.A.X = 10;
r.A.Y = 10;
r.B.X = 100;
r.B.Y = 100;
```

the assignments are all invalid, since r.A and r.B are not variables.

Comment: Thank you, Abel. Your explanation (returning a value is same as copying it) is the exactly piece o techie that I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Although properties look like variables, each property is really a combination of a get method and/or a set method.  Typically a property get method will return a copy of what's in some variable or array slot, and a put method will copy its parameter into that variable or array slot.  If one wants to do something like `someVariable = someObject.someProeprty;` or `someobject.someProperty = someVariable;`, it won't matter that those statements end up being executed as `var temp=someObject.somePropertyBackingField; someVariable=temp;` and `var temp=someVariable; someObject.somePropertyBackingField=temp;`, respectively.  On the other hand, there are some operations which can be done with fields but cannot be done with properties.

If an object `George` exposes a field named `Field1`, then code may pass `George.Field` as a `ref` or `out` parameter to another method.  Additionally, if the type of `Field1` is a value type with exposed fields, then an attempt to access those fields will access the fields of the struct that is stored within `George`.  If `Field1` has exposed properties or methods, then accessing those will cause `George.Field1` to be passed to those methods as though it were a `ref` parameter.

If `George` exposes a property named `Property1`, then an access of `Property1` which is not the left side of an assignment operator will call the "get" method and store its result in a temporary variable.  An attempt to read a field of `Property1` will read that field from the temporary variable.  An attempt to call a property getter or method on `Property1` will pass that temporary variable as a `ref` parameter to that method and then discard it after the method returns.  Within the method or property getter or method, `this` will refer to the temporary variable, and any changes the method makes to `this` will be discarded.

Because it would make no sense to write to fields of a temporary variable, attempts to write to fields of a property are forbidden.  Additionally, present versions of the C# compiler will guess that property setters would be likely to modify `this` and will thus forbid any use of property setters even when they would in fact not modify the underlying structure [e.g. the reason `ArraySegment` includes an indexed `get` method and not an indexed `set` method is that if one were to try to say e.g. `thing.theArraySegment[3] = 4;` the compiler would think one was trying to trying to modify the structure returned by the `theArraySegment` property, rather than modify the array whose reference is encapsulated therein].  It would be extremely useful if one could specify that particular structure methods will modify `this` and should not be invokable on structure properties, but as yet no mechanism exists for that.

If one wants to write to a field contained within a property, the best pattern is usually:

```
var temp = myThing.myProperty; // Assume `temp` is a coordinate-point structure
temp.X += 5;
myThing.myProperty = temp;
```

If the type of `myProperty` is designed to encapsulate a fixed set of related but independent values (such as the coordinates of a point), it's best if it exposes those variables as fields.  Although some people seem to prefer to design structs so as to require constructs like:

```
var temp = myThing.myProperty; // Assume `temp` is some kind of XNA Point structure
myThing.myProperty = new CoordinatePoint(temp.X+5, temp.Y);
```

I would regard such code as less readable, less efficient, and more error-prone than the previous style.  Among other things, if `CoordinatePoint` happens to e.g. expose a constructor with parameters X,Y,Z as well as a constructor which takes parameters X,Y and assumes Z is zero, code like the second form would zero out Z without any indication that it was doing so (intentionally or unintentionally).  By contrast, if `X` is an exposed field, it's much clearer that the first form would *only* modify `X`.

In some cases, it may be helpful for a class to expose an internal field or array slot via a method that passes it as a `ref` parameter to a user-defined routine, e.g. a `List<T>`-like class might expose:

```
delegate void ActByRef<T1>(ref T1 p1);
delegate void ActByRef<T1,T2>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2);

void ActOnItem(int index, ActByRef<T> proc)
{
  proc(ref BackingArray[index]);
}
void ActOnItem<PT>(int index, ActByRef<T,PT> proc, ref PT extraParam)
{
  proc(ref BackingArray[index], ref extraParam);
}
```

Code which had a `FancyList<CoordinatePoint>` and wanted to add some local variable `dx` to field X of item 5 in iit could then do:

```
myList.ActOnItem(5, (ref Point pt, ref int ddx) => pt.X += ddx, ref dx);
```

Note that this approach would allow in-place modification of data in the list, and even allow the use of such methods as `Interlocked.CompareExchange`).  Unfortunately, there's no possible mechanism by which a type which derives from `List<T>` can support such a method, and no mechanism by which a type which does support such a method can be passed to code which expects a `List<T>`.

Comment: Many thanks, Supercat... I'd accept your answer, but I can only accept 1, and Anders Abel was a little bit faster than you, but your text is remarkable (very well detailed)... ^_^