# C# anonymous value types nature

Tags: c#, immutability, anonymous-types

Consider the flowing code snippet

```
static void Main()
    {
        var x = new MyStruct
        {
            Item = new StringWrapper("abc")
        };

        Console.WriteLine(x.Item.PublicField);
        x.Item.SetValue("xyz");
        Console.WriteLine(x.Item.PublicField);

        var y = new
        {
            Item = new StringWrapper("abc")
        };

        Console.WriteLine(y.Item.PublicField);
        y.Item.SetValue("xyz");
        Console.WriteLine(y.Item.PublicField);
    }

    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public StringWrapper Item;
    }

    public struct StringWrapper
    {
        public string PublicField;

        public StringWrapper(string v)
        {
            PublicField = v;
        }

        public void SetValue(string v)
        {
            PublicField = v;
        }
    }
```

And the output:
abc
xyz
abc
abc

MyStruct can be declared as class, and the output will remain the same.
{abc, abc} part of output is a surprise for me, as I expect anonymous type to be converted to class or struct and behave the same.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here and will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292087/accessing-and-changing-structs-as-property-vs-as-field, you can find more explanations by searching - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+struct+field+vs+property

Comment: `class StringWrapper` will solve it. have to mention that properties in anonymous type are readonly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference here is that your `MyStruct` (struct or class) exposes a public field while anonymous classes (`new { }`) expose public properties.

When you access a value type from a field or variable, you do not get a copy, you access the instance directly. Therefore making changes to it stores them in the instance.

When you instead access it via a property or method, you get a returned copy of your `StringWrapper` and changing that doesn't change what is stored in the anonymous classes private field.

Just to demonstrate, you can get the same behavior by making your `Item` field a property too:

```
public StringWrapper Item { get; set; }
```